# what is the difference between INSTEAD OF and AFTER trigger in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

What is the difference between INSTEAD OF and AFTER trigger in SQL Server?

INSTEAD OF trigger invoked before unique key constraint, will the AFTER trigger invoke after  unique key constraint?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

AFTER trigger fires **after** a DML operation.
INSTEAD OF trigger fires **instead of** a DML operation.

Big difference. INSTEAD OF allows you to override functionality, or implement functionality that otherwise isn't supported. The common place I use it is to create updateable views. Sometimes a view may not be key preserved, but as the designer you may know which base table(s) you want to update so you can do it by writing specific logic to do the update behind the scenes. An alternative is just to write a stored procedure and force the developers to call those procedures instead of performing DML on a view, but DML on views is a nice abstraction, in my opinion, because developers can treat views like tables. That is how relational design is meant to be.

Regarding "after unique key constraint", the AFTER trigger will happen after the DML succeeds, so it will happen after any violations (which will force a rollback).

Comment: 'AFTER' triggers don't fire when there is a constraint violation (because the statement is failing and being rolled back before it would be reached). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms179304(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Answer (score 3):

After trigger  executes after data modification while Instead of trigger executes prior to data modification.